# Dynamically binding and creating items with complex database structure to Create and Edit views using viewModel in MVC 3 with EF4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, razor, viewmodel

I had bad times trying to figure out how to deal with this. Any help wold be appreciated. Even a suggestion of a better structure that fits to my needs: **Construct category items in a category having an specification of how they can be in a category item property list.**

This is used to, among other things, dinamicaly generate forms for creating and editing items.

**Long story short:** I need to know if I'm doing it right or a better (maybe automated) way of deal with it without breaking the whole app.
.
.

I'm working with MySQL 5 in VWD Express 2010 in a Win7 64bit machine with all MySQL drivers intalled (ODBC and .NET specific provider, the last one is not compatible with ASP.Net 4). Other problem rised here, but can be target for a separate question: I'm writing all of my models, 'cause MySql isn't compatible with the Linq to SQL (I can imagine why, but not sure).
.
.

**Returning to the real topic:**

My models are:

- `Category` - Them main entity, with a name property, a collection of `CategoryItemProperty` entities and a collection of `Item` entities;
- `CategoryItemProperty` - An entity with a name and some other properties that dictate how the `Items` in this category may be (field size, mask, input restriction, etc);
- `Item` - The entity whose properties are based on the category properties;
- `ItemProperty` - The properties of the items (field size, mask, input restriction, etc)

The code is something around this:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set }
    public string Description { get; set }
    //...
    public virtual List<CategoryItemProperty> ItemProperties { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryItemProperty
{
    public int CategoryItemPropertyId { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public int MaxLenght { get; set; }
    //...
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    //...
    public virtual Category Category { get; set }
    public virtual List<ItemProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class ItemProperty
{
    public int ItemPropertyId { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryItemPropertyId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    //...
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    public virtual CategoryItemProperty CategoryItemProperty { get; set; }
}
```

.
.

The big problem here, with this approach, is to generate the form and deal with the data on the controller side to be saved to the database.

.
.

**A more detailed example wold be:** Generate a simple contact form:

We create a `Category` with some field specification:

```
var category = new Category() { Description = "Simple Contact Form" };

MyEntitySet.Categories.Add(category);
MyEntitySet.SaveChanges();

//...

var name = new CategoryItemProperty() { Label = "Name", Size = 50, MaxLength = 50 };
var message = new CategoryItemProperty() { Label = "Message", Size = 50, MaxLength = 255 };

category.ItemProperties.Add(name);
category.ItemProperties.Add(message);

MyEntitySet.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;

MyEntitySet.SaveChanges();
```

.
.

What I have came up until now is to create a `ViewModel` to pass the category info and its item property collection to the Create and Edit views and doing a loop through the `ItemProperties` to generate the fields and working in the `ItemController`, receiving the `FormCollection` and generating the `Item` and its `ItemProperty`s objects and saving them to the database. But this process is terrible and painfull:

.

**Items/Create View:**

```
@model MyApp.Models.CategoryItemModelView

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description);    
...
@foreach(var property in Model.ItemProperties)
{
    <label>@property.Label</label>
    <input type="text" name="@property.Name" size="@item.Size" maxlength="@item.MaxLength" />
}
```

**In the Controller:**

```
// GET: /Items/Create/5
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
   var categoryItemModelView = new CategoryItemModelView();
   categoryItemModelView.Populate(id); // this method maps the category POCO to the ViewModel

   return View(categoryItemModelView);
}

// POST: /Items/Create/5
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(int id, FormCollection formData)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       var category = MyEntitySet.Categories.Find(id);

       var item = new Item
       {
           CategoryId = id,
           Description = formData["Description"],
           // ...
           Category = category
       };
       MyEntitySet.Items.Add(item);

       foreach(var property in category.ItemProperties)
       {
           var itemProperty = new ItemProperty
           {
               ItemId = item.ItemId,
               CategoryItemPropertyId = property.Id,
               Value = form[property.Name],
               // ...
               Item = item,
               CategoryItemProperty = property
           };

           MyEntitySet.ItemProperties.Add(itemProperty);
       }

       MyEntitySet.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // Here I don't know how to return the typed data to the user (the form returns empty)
    var categoryItemModelView = new CategoryItemModelView(id);
    categoryItemModelView.Populate(id); // this method maps the category POCO to the ViewModel

    return View(categoryItemModelView);
}
```

.
.

My problem rises in building the Create and Edit actions and its respective views (see above how I'm doing it right now). **How to handle this case, when I have to use the `Category.ItemProperties` to generate the fields and store the information in an `Item` object and the field values in its `ItemProperty` object?**

.
.

**Please note:** All this code is for example purposes only. My code is similar, but its handled by a specific controller and specific views to CRUD Categories and CategoryItemProperties and I have no problem with this.

.
.

Sorry for this long text. I've tryed to be as clearest as I can. If you need any more info, drop a comment, please.

Comment: Somehow in that large amount of text I lost your problem so what is the question?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to build a web form framework like wufoo or something. You mention it's kind of terrible, and that makes sense. I think you're using frameworks that are intended for you to statically model entities and their attributes. But what you need to do is make a totally dynamic UI and model engine...reminds me of the EAV pattern in SQL Server, in which case it is going to be hard to query this data. I'm sure it's doable with enough effort but you might think of your web form definitions as documents and consider a document database instead of a relational database. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I'll have to go on with my solution for now. I can think in creating a mongo database for this case, but all of the other features are already runing on a MySQL server. Anyway,  I'll wait to see if someone have another insite about my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay rcdmk! first of all my English is terrible and i'm here to just share with you my few experience.

I have build such a complex software in the past with MVVM(WPF) + EF4 + T4 to generate **POCO**'s and i deal with **Microsoft Blend** to handle with actions, bindings and so on between the client and the viewmodels!

that's work great! i hope i helped you!

ps:
I dont know if Blend supports ASP.Net but creating POCO(Viewmodel) with lazy loading could help u somewhere!

Comment: I think a bottle of Whiskey is more helpful than Expression Blend to solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry. My English isn't very good as well and I'm not sure about what you wanna say but I think its something about using T4 templates to generate the views. Correct me if I'm missing the point.

Comment: Just search here on StackO or on google for : Entity Framework + T4 + Poco you will have enough to clearlier respond your question! My Idea for you is to read about it! If u create poco objects they will "replace" your Models and you can deal with the object context in your controller to CRUD! How to use EF4 with Mysql you can read this : http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/12/09/getting-mysql-work-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx  .... sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0):

As i understand , Category and corresponding CategoryPropertyItems is describing how Item will be created . Simply Category is drawing an abstract form and item and item properties are concretes (because item property has Value property).  So in Item/Create Action (GET) you can build item and it's properties using Category and CategoryPropertyItems.

public Item Build(Category category)
        {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.Category = category;
            item.ItemId = ...

```
        foreach(var categoryItemProperty in category.ItemProperties)
        {
            ItemProperty itemProperty = new ItemProperty();
            itemProperty.Item = item;
            itemProperty.CategoryItemProperty = categoryItemProperty;
            itemProperty.ItemPropertyId = ... 
        }

        return item;
    }
```

In result of Index/Create Action you can use  either just this Item object or you can put item into ViewModel .

In View you can bind  direcly to model (Item) properties .

This links can help you .

[Editing and binding nested lists with ASP.NET MVC 2](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/06/06/editing-and-binding-nested-lists-with-asp-net-mvc-2/)
[Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Comment: Hi. That is exactly what I have by now and was the reason I've posted my question here, as you can see in the last part of the post. Anyway, thanks for the links. They gave me some ideas to play.